# How to display a JPanel when a JMenu is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, awt

When 'homeMenu' is clicked, "Menu selected" and "Menu deselected" are both displayed on the console, while the panel does not appear. How should make the panel appear when 'homeMenu' is clicked?

```
public class MyClass extends JApplet{
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu fileMenu, homeMenu;

    public MyClass () {
        setTheMenuBar();
    }

    void setTheMenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        homeMenu = new JMenu("Home");
        menuBar.add(homeMenu);
        homeMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            p.add(new JButton("yara"));
            add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            System.out.println("Menu selected");
        }

        @Override
        public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu deselected");
        }

        @Override
        public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu canceled");
        }
    });

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // TODO code application logic here
           MyClass applet = new MyClass();
           JFrame frame = new JFrame();
           frame.add(applet);
           frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
           frame.setVisible(true);
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           applet.start();
      }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: Still doesn't work in my case

Comment: [edit] the question to show your attempt.

Comment: BTW 1) Post a [mcve]. 2) Don't mix Swing with AWT components. That `Button` should be a `JButton`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson oh yes! typo mistake. I typed this line in the site, not in my compiler.

Comment: Now my code is complete! :)

Comment: There's no mention of `CardLayout` in the code above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193592/discussion-between-yara-raffoul-and-andrew-thompson).